# How to insert 4 newlines before pattern match with SED?

Tags: macos, shell, sed, terminal

How to enter 4 blanklines before pattern matches?

I can do

```
sed '/patterntosearch4/G' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

to create a new file (2.txt) with a blank line AFTER each pattern.

But how to enter 4 blank lines BEFORE match?

Manpage SED didnt seem to provide any answers.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Regex with back-reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/patterntosearch4/i\\n\n\n' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
sed -e '/patterntosearch4/!b' -e 'G' -e 's/\(.*\)\(.\)/\2\2\2\2\1/' file
```

BTW as you use the `G` command, which inserts a newline following the line with the pattern match, I guessed you wanted a newline inserted before the line with the pattern match.

Comment: Thanks, your 2nd answered solved my problem!
PS The first one just generated 4 times the letter N in front of it, dont know why?

Answer (score 5):

In the famous sed one-line blog (http://www.catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt)

```
# insert a blank line above every line which matches "regex"
 sed '/regex/{x;p;x;}'
```

so in your case,

```
sed '/atterntosearch4/{x;p;p;p;p;x}' file
```

or

```
sed '/atterntosearch4/{x;P;P;P;P;x}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

an alternative by sed, without substitution (`s/../../`):

```
sed '/pat/{x;p;p;p;p;x}'
```

test:

```
kent$ (master|✔) seq 5|sed '/3/{x;p;p;p;p;x}'      
1
2




3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu-sed you can do:

```
sed -i.bak 's/pattern/\n\n\n\n&/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many more ways, but here you have one very straightforward:

```
sed 's/patterntosearch4/\n\n\n\n&/' 1.txt > 2.txt
```